# Trouble Detecting Process.Exited Event

Tags: c#, pdf, process, system.diagnostics

In part of my code, I attempt to execute a process to open a PDF File. I need to follow up only when the process ends.

> Initially, I tried setting up an event driven approach as follows:

```
    process = Process.Start(_pdfFilePath);

    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Exit += OnProcessExit;

    private void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Calculate and print results
    }
```

However, what ends up happening is, the event never gets fired (tried with and without both **EnableRasingEvents** and **WaitForExit**).

> My second approach felt inappropriate but worked in first sight:

```
    process = Process.Start(_pdfFilePath);

    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.WaitForExit();

    OnProcessExit();


    private void OnProcessExit()
    {
        // Calculate and print results
    }
```

I assumed that since the WaitForExit() method freezes the thread my main form is running on, it would recreate the result I need. However, it turns out, the calculations are printed upon OPENING the file, not after termination.

> In a third desperate attempt, I simply added a check as follows:

```
    process = Process.Start(_pdfFilePath);

    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.WaitForExit();

    if(process.HasExited)    
    OnProcessExit();


    private void OnProcessExit()
    {
        // Calculate and print results
    }
```

But the check had no effect.

Any ideas as to why process termination is not detected properly? Were the methods intended to work ideally with Windows operations and applications only?

Comment: It's not clear why your code attempts to use both the Exited event and WaitForExit().  Doesn't WaitForExit on its own do what you need - ie block until the process ends?

Comment: You haven't provided enough context. So your question is off-topic, lacking a good [mcve]. However, note that when `UseShellExecute` is `true`, as in when you are starting a process by specifying a file instead of an actual executable, in _some_ cases the underlying native call to `ShellExecuteEx()` will not return a process handle, making it impossible for the `Process` class to wait for the process exit. You can look at the `Process.Handle` property value to see if this might be the case.

Comment: @peterG That's honestly the point I am trying to convey here. I am using the WaitForExit method, yet the function below it is fired before the process exits. There is no reason I am using WaitForExit() and Exited together, I just tried doing it with and without the WaitForExit method - both yielding unfavorable results as described above.

Comment: @PeterDuniho According to the debugger, the Process.Handle is an int pointer and it has some number assigned to it. I would assume that is what I should expect to see if it's working?

Comment: I would also like to add - although the event firing isn't working as intended, the HasExited bool variable does return the appropriate value, and it successfully managed to fire the function only when the application is closed. However, I would still appreciate it if I could understand why the Exited event fails.

Comment: _"I would assume that is what I should expect to see"_ -- yes, a non-zero value indicates there's some hope to get this to work and that the problem very likely lies only in your code. _"I would still appreciate it if I could understand why the Exited event fails"_ -- not possible to answer without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. See also [ask], including the articles linked at the bottom of that page.